# Prove whether statement is true or false

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Consider the following questions:

> True or false? Prove separately that the following are correct
>
> 1. If $ A \vDash B$ and $ \lnot A \vDash B$, then $\rm\vDash B$
> 2. If $A ∧ B \vDash C$, then $A \vDash C$

First, I translated the two questions into English:

- If A implies B and not A implies B, then B is a tautology
- If A and B implies C, then A implies C

Looking through the class text, most of these proofs are done by interpreting the question and comparing truth table values to try and find a counter example. I guess since it's easier to try to disprove it first.

For question 1, I went ahead and drew some truth tables for A → B and ¬A → B and tried to compare values when B is a tautology.

For question 2 I tried applying the definition of logical consequence to the problem. I have a feeling that it's false, but I'm having a hard time finding a counter example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "weather the statements" should be "whether the statements" ;) The truth-table approach is fine for 1. The first part says it's never the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. The second part says it's never the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. Therefore, it's never the case that $B$ is false.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, Sorry, I'm confused you said "it's never the case that A is true and B is false" twice.

Comment: The second instance was supposed to be "it's never the case that $A$ is **false** and $B$ is false."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that $B$ is true if $A$ is so, and also that $B$ is true if $A$ is not, then *can* you just claim $B$ is true?

Ie: Does a truth table demonstrate that $B$ is true when *both* $A\to B$ and $\neg A\to B$ are true.

$$\begin{array}{c:c|c:c| c} A & B & A\to B & \neg A\to B & ((A\to B)\wedge(\neg A\to B))\to B \\\hline \top & \top\\ \bot & \top \\ \top & \bot \\ \bot & \bot \\\hline  \end{array}$$

---

If it is only guaranteed that $C$ is true if both $A$ and $B$ are true, then *is it okay* to claim $C$ is true if $A$ is true (but $B$ *may* not be)?

Ie Does a truth table demonstrate that $A\to C$ is true when $(A\wedge B)\to C$

$$\begin{array}{c:c:c|c:c: c|c} A & B & C & (A\wedge B)\to C & A\to C & ((A\wedge B)\to C)\to(A\to C) \\\hline \top & \top & \top \\ \bot & \top & \top \\ \top & \bot & \top \\ \bot & \bot & \top \\ \top & \top & \bot \\ \bot & \top & \bot \\ \top & \bot & \bot \\ \bot &\bot & \bot \\\hline  \end{array}$$